# Switch Item Slots in Minecraft using a Command Block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to be able to set the active hotbar slot with a command instead of the mouse wheel or keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>1</kbd> through <kbd>9</kbd>).  I don't need to move items around in the hotbar, I just need to be able to set the active slot.

I have searched for this quite a while now and haven't found anything useful yet. Can somebody please tell me how I can achieve this for a given player?

Comment: What have you tried already?  Are you looking to just set the active slot to something else, or swap the items between two slots?  Without a little more information, it's going to be hard for us to help you.

Comment: Im just trying to switch for example from the second slot in the hotbar to the first one without having to scroll or press 1. so I think its the first thing you mentioned. I haven't tried anything special yet because I'm not really an expert using command blocks. i didn't find a command matching what I'm searching yet. Do you need any more information?

Comment: No, that should be good.  I've edited your question to be a little more clear as to what you want.

Comment: Thank you :D Yes this is what I was trying to say / ask.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can't do it in Vanilla Minecraft. Selected slot is a NBT value. To change it you would use `/entitydata`, but the command doesn't work on players, only mobs and other entities. You can still use mods or Bukkit/Spigot Plugins, but vanilla commands won't work.

Answer (score -2):

There is a way of changing someones hotbar in the the new 1.8 with the `/replaceitem` command. Go to [**Here**](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#replaceitem) for a tutorial on the `/replaceitem` command. Hope this helps what your doing!

Comment: This command cannot change the active hotbar slot, only replace items.